# How to prove a relationship when my unmarried non-EU partner travels to the UK with a 'Family member of an EU citizen' residence card?

Tags: visas, uk, eu-citizens

My partner is Chinese, I am British, but we both live in the Netherlands. He has a "Residence card for a family member of an EU citizen" which we obtained even though we are unmarried because we had lived together for over 6 months, and that qualified us under EU law.

Next month we are planning to travel to the UK together. As I understand, he does not need an entry visa if he travels with me, however the gov.uk website says that he needs to provide:

"evidence that you are the family member of an EEA citizen (for example, your marriage certificate or birth certificate)"

What evidence should we provide if he got the Article 10 residence card when unmarried?

We have a 'samenlevingscontract' (a notarized contract that we are living together,) but I am afraid that will not be enough at the border.

(I'm just worried that we might face trouble at the border because he isn't a family member despite qualifying for the Article 10 card.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *samenlevingscontract* is indeed the evidence of your relationship.

If you want additional evidence, the most useful thing would be anything that ties his residence card to you.  If the card itself mentions your name, great.  If not, a copy of the application materials showing that you are the EU citizen on whom the application was based should serve that purpose.

In practice, it seems from anecdotal evidence, you are not particularly likely to be asked for documentary evidence of your relationship, but you will certainly want to have it on hand just in case.

Comment: Anything can be evidence. evidence you have the same address; joint bank accounts; joint leasing or mortgages; even photos of you together on romantic occasions can help.